# Problem regarding the extension of a map from a closed subset of a locally compact separable metric space to where the target space is $K(G,n).$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $X$ is a locally compact, separable metric space and $A\subset X$ be closed. Assume all the cohomology groups here are Čech cohomology. Let $G$ be an abelian group and $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ If the homomorphism $j^n_{X,A} : H^n(X;G)\to H^n(A;G)$ is a surjection, then show that every continuous map $f : A\to K(G,n)$ can be extended to a continuous map from $X\to K(G,n)$ where $K(G,n)$ is the Eilenberg-McLane space of type $(G,n).$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ By the Brown Representation theorem , as $H^n$ is a half-exact functor, so the group of all homotopy classes of maps from $C$ to $K(G,n)$ i.e. $[C,K(G,n)]$ is isomorphic to $H^n(C;G)$ where $C$ is a countable $CW$-complex
. But can we apply Brown Representation theorem for any locally compact, separable metric space ? If yes, then any map $f : A\to K(G,n)$ is homotopic to a map $g\mid_{A}$ where $g$ is a map from $X$ to $K(G,n)$ but how can we show the equality of $f$ with some $\tilde{g}\mid_{A}$ where $\tilde{g}\mid_{A} : X\to K(G,n) ?$ I think it's quite easy but I can't see it immediately. Thanks for any hints, references etc.

P.S. : Actually, the problem arose during proving that the cohomological dimension of a locally compact space separable metric space $X,$ $\operatorname{dim}_GX \leq n$ if and only if for any closed subset $A\subset X,$ any map from $A$ to $K(G,n)$ has a continuous extension from the whole space $X$ to $K(G,n).$ The long exact sequence for the pair $(X,A)$ for Čech cohomology gives the fact that the homomorphism $j^n_{X,A}$ is a surjection if and only if $\operatorname{dim}_GX \leq n$ but transferring the problem to the homotopy classs of maps to $K(G,n)$ initiated my doubts. In many books and articles, they have been assumed to be true without any proof and so I think it's not that difficult but I am unable to see anything immediately.

Comment: Assuming $(X,A)$ is a CW-pair, you can solve your second question via the homotopy extension property of cofibrations. I don't know from the top of my head if this assumption is valid.

Comment: If $H^n(-;G)$ is Cech cohomology with coefficients in $G$, then $H^n(X;G)\cong [X,K(G,n)]$ for any metric space $X$ (more generally when $X$ is paracompact $T_2$ space). This doesn't hold in general for singular cohomology. Case in point, let $X$ be Warsaw circle and $n=1$.

Comment: Thanks and I have edited with adding a Post-script.

Comment: To complete from my last point, if $G$ is finitely-generated abelian you can realise $K(G,n)$ as a metric ANR (any realisation by a locally finite simplicial complex will do). Any closed metric pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property with respect to such a space.

Comment: @Tyrone Can you please provide a quick reference to the fact that $K(G,n)$ is a metric $ANR ?$ Although we are taking countable abelian groups for the problem .

Comment: Most people recognise $K(G,n)$ as a homotopy type rather than as a space. You should take this into account whilst trying to formulate your problem correctly. What is true is that there is a countable, locally finite CW complex in the homotopy type of $K(G,n)$. Such a space is metrisable and is an ANR. These last statements are contained in chapter 5.2 of Fritsch and Piccinini's book *Cellular Structures in Topology*. See especially Theorem 5.2.3. Do you see how to realise $K(G,n)$ as a countable complex to begin with?

Comment: @Tyrone, thanks & sorry for late reply. Yes, I see now how $K(G,n)$ has homotopy type of a metric $ANR.$ Can we also say that $K(G,n)$ has the homotopy type of a countable $CW$-complex if $G$ is countable ?

Comment: Yes, it is . It has been stated in Pg. $14$ of Hilton's book $\textit{General Cohomology Theory and $K$-Theory}$.